# Android Animation : Animate view to the centre of parent layout

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, objectanimator

I am trying to implement a bunch of animations on different views which are components of a splash screen.

I have read up on Property Animations on the developer site but I can't figure out how to animate a view(translate + scale) to the centre of the parent layout. If I pass the value 50% or 50% p to the valueFrom attribute in  it crashes saying that it is an invalid value.

How do I achieve this? My current animator xml is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<set>
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:valueFrom="50%"
        android:valueTo="50%" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="y"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="50%" />
</set>
```

Comment: Can the person who down voted please elaborate or suggest  an edit to the above question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in code programmatically:

The following code animates a view from the top left to the center of the screen.

```
    // Run on UI thread so that the height and widths are set
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Assign the animation which makes it drop down into view
            View view = yourParentView.findViewById(R.id.view);
            View yourParentView = findViewById(R.id.parent);
            int parentHeight = yourParentView.getHeight();
            int parentWidth = yourParentView.getWidth();
            int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
            int viewWidth = view.getWidth();

            Animation animation = getAnimation((parentHeight / 2) - (viewHeight / 2), (parentWidth / 2) - (viewWidth / 2));
            view.startAnimation(animation);
        }

    };
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(r );

private static AnimationSet getAnimation(int x, int y)  {

    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    animSet.addAnimation(new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, x, y));
    animSet.setDuration(DURATION);
    return animSet;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rob. I am trying to achieve this using property animations. Also I want to keep animations in xmls(as far as possible)

Comment: @Rohan check my edit and see if that is useful, if so I will amend my answer to remove the first bit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The xml bit did not work as well.

Comment: xFraction and yFraction are not really properties of an ImageView(Or view) right? How is it supposed to animate between those values if the property itself does not exist?

Comment: @Rohan Is there any reason it has to be an object animator? I think using percentages is supported using a Translation animation e.g. `<translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-70%" android:duration="1000"/>` but not sure about objectAnimator.

Comment: The reason for using property animations is that it is not limited to views like View Animations. Also, view animations can only animate specific attributes of a view(from the official documentation).

Comment: But you are only using the animator for a view correct? Seems better to use the provided animator which is better suited for the task.